# No output given by stdout.readlines()

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, paramiko

This is a simple code that logs into a linux box, and execute a grep to a resource on the box. I just need to be able to view the output of the command I execute, but nothing is returned. Code doesn't report any error but the desired output is not written.

Below is the code:

```
import socket
import re
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('linux_box', port=22, username='abc', password='xyz')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('grep xyz *.set')
output2 = stdout.readlines()
type(output2)
```

---

This is the output I get:

C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Python34/Paramiko.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually print anything to standard output.

Changing last line to `print(output2)` should print value correctly.

Your code was likely based on interactive Python shell experiments, where return value of last executed command is printed to standard output implicitly. In non-interactive mode such behavior does not occur. That's why you need to use `print` function explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for replying Rogalski. I replaced the last line in the code with print(output2), but this time I get an empty braces:    []

Process finished with exit code 0
I have verfied on the box that I do get a result for the command I which I am running.

Comment: I used the same code on a router with commands & it worked. Meaning the code is correct, but not sure this wouldn't work on the linux box.